# Can Ada95 child subunits be used to separate code for maintainability?

Tags: ada

I have created an Ada class whose implementation has become quite large. I have a multiple body only methods that I would like move to a separate file for maintainability/readability purposes.

- My understanding with Ada95 Separates is that you can only have one method per file. I have about 20 methods I want to separate but it is undesirable to me to create 20 separate files for this functions.
- To separate the code I was thinking I could create a child package. Then the parent body could call the child class.

**Q.1** `In Ada, Is it wrong/undesirable for a Parent Body unit to depend on a child Unit?`

*EDIT: The above question is too vague and any answer would be subjective.*

**Q.2** `How can I divide my code into separate files without creating an over abundance of files?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact you can have `separate` bodies for packages, protected and task types, as well as subprograms.

So you could say

```
package Large is
   procedure A;
   procedure B;
end Large;

package body Large is
   package Implementation is
      procedure A;
      procedure B;
   end Implementation;
   package body Implementation is separate;
   procedure A renames Implementation.A;
   procedure B renames Implementation.B;
end Large;

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
separate (Large)
package body Implementation is
   procedure A is
   begin
      Put_Line ("large.implementation.a");
   end A;
   procedure B is
   begin
      Put_Line ("large.implementation.b");
   end B;
end Implementation;
```

and to check

```
with Large;
procedure Check_Separate_Implementation is
begin
   Large.A;
   Large.B;
end Check_Separate_Implementation;
```

Equally, you could have `Implementation` as a child package:

```
private package Large.Implementation is
   procedure A;
   procedure B;
end Large.Implementation;

with Large.Implementation;
package body Large is
   procedure A renames Implementation.A;
   procedure B renames Implementation.B;
end Large;
```

The only difference I can see is that other child packages of `Large` would be able to see `Implementation` in the child package version but not in the separate version.

The [Program Structure section of the Ada Style Guide (2005 edition)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Style_Guide/Program_Structure) strongly prefers use of child packages rather than subunits, and says (in answer to your style question)

> In preference to nesting in a package body, use a private child and with it to the parent body.

but, as you might expect, opinions will differ on this. You could read the *Rationale* section of the Guide and see how it fits your particular situation.

Comment: Thank you @Simon Wright! This is exactly the solution that I originally sought. I'm not sure that it answers the original question of correctness to depend on a child unit. I have updated my question to reflect my intent.

Comment: @Jerunh, I added a note about the Ada Style Guide.

Answer (score -1):

About the "correctness" of having a body (not a spec, you would get a circular dependency) depending on a child package, I use that all the time and I find it very convenient, especially to implement some complex data structure/service used internally by my package.  The [Ada Style guide (2005)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Style_Guide/Program_Structure#Child_Library_Units) agrees with me when it says

> Use child packages to implement a subsystem

I guess this is your case too.